# edit checkbox value in php

Tags: php, html

my code is

```
<div class="data" style="margin-top:15px;">
    <div class="label1">Accreditation By:</div>
        <div style="text-align:right;width:65px;float:left;">
    <label for="a">COFRAC</label><input type="checkbox" name="accreditation_cofrac" value="cofrac" id="a" ></div>   
    <div class="label2" >
        <label for="b">NABL</label><input type="checkbox" name="accreditation_nabl" value="nabl" id="b" >

    </div>
</div>
```

how can i edit these checkbox value in php

Comment: Edit them in what way?

Comment: I like to edit checkbox values from forms using the Dark Arts more than PHP. It's more challenging that way. I tried to use *the Force*, but that didn't get me anywhere...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> i use this code now its ok..

```
<div class="data" style="margin-top:15px;">
                    <div class="label1">Accreditation By:</div>
                        <div style="text-align:right;width:65px;float:left;">
                    <label for="a">COFRAC</label><input type="checkbox" name="accreditation_cofrac" value="cofrac" <?php 
                     $is_checked=$row['ACCREDITATION_BY'];
                      if(($is_checked=="cofrac") || ($is_checked=="cofrac nabl") )
                    echo $is_checked ? "checked" : " " 
                    ?> 
                    id="a" /> </div>    
                    <div class="label2" >
                        <label for="b">NABL</label><input type="checkbox" name="accreditation_nabl" value="nabl"  <?php 
                         $is_checked=$row['ACCREDITATION_BY']; 
                         if(($is_checked=="nabl")|| ($is_checked=="cofrac nabl") )
                         echo $is_checked ? "checked" : " " 
                         ?> id="b" />

                    </div>
                    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can change dynamically  like

```
<input type="checkbox" name="accreditation_nabl" value="<?php if(isset($dynamicvar)){echo $dynamicvar;}else {echo 'nabl';}?>" id="b" >
```

`$dynamicvar` (will be your value you want to change)